# SQL date column update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date-formatting

I have a table with some columns. The table has `executedate (char(12))` and has values such `2003/1/2`, `2004/01/12`, `2002/1/02`, `2002/05/09`

I want to make them to the format `yyyy/mm/dd`.

How can I do that?

Comment: what is the database that you are using

Comment: Use proper _date_ data type!

Comment: **Never** store dates in varchar columns. Just don't. If you fix that horrible design choice, you can easily format dates into any format you want.

Comment: I use MS SQL database

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use`parsename`. Here is a sample

```
declare @t table (
    executedate char(12)
)

insert into @t 
values 
('2003/1/2')
, ('2004/01/12')
, ('2002/1/02')
, ('2002/05/09')

select 
    executedate
    , newVal = parsename(val, 3) + '/' + right('00' + parsename(val, 2), 2)
     + '/' + right('00' + parsename(val, 1), 2)
from 
    @t
    cross apply (select val = rtrim(replace(executedate, '/', '.'))) q1
```